# Array "out of bounds"

Tags: java, arrays, jtextfield, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I'm using an array of String[3] to store user input which is got from 4 JTextFields
I then output the array to a txt file:

```
String[] userInfo = new String[3];
    userInfo[0] = sourceTextField.getText();
    userInfo[1] = usernameTextField.getText();
    userInfo[2] = passwordTextField.getText();
    userInfo[3] = emailTextField.getText();
    for (String userInfo1 : userInfo) {
        try 
        {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Peace Infinity\\Desktop\\[programming]Projects\\DataFiles\\PasswordRepository.txt", true));
            String s;
            s = userInfo1;
            writer.write(s + " ");
            writer.flush();
        }catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(ADD_dialogBox_v1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error processing file!");
        }
    }
```

Can someone tell me why I'm getting exception "array index out of bounds"?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you declare an array you provide the length/size of that array.
An array starts at index 0 as you've done in your code, but you're trying to assign a value
to an index "out of bounds" - the fourth index.

```
new String[3] // index 0,1,2
new String[4] // index 0,1,2,3
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it working.. it was a stupid question actually. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

solution is very simple

```
String[] userInfo = new String[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a smaller Array....
do this

```
String[] userInfo = new String[4];
```

I would suggest you to use `Arraylist` as this does not require any size to declare and can accomodate any number of items.

```
  ArrayList<String> userInfo = new ArrayList<>();
    userInfo.add(sourceTextField.getText());
    userInfo.add(usernameTextField.getText());
    userInfo.add(passwordTextField.getText());
    userInfo. dd(emailTextField.getText());
     for (String userInfo1 : userInfo) {
        try 
        {.......
           ............
```

And the rest of the code proccessed accordingly....

Comment: U r Welcome @noBrainer. If this really helps you then don't forget to plus one and Accept the Answer as it will help future visitors of this post.